# Logging failed packets with Calico

Tags: kubernetes, networking, calico

I have a network policy

```
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default
  namespace: test
spec:
  selector: app == 'nginx'
  ingress:
    - action: Log
      destination: {}
      protocol: TCP
      source: {}
  egress:
    - action: Allow
      destination:
        services:
          name: kube-dns
          namespace: kube-system
    - action: Allow
      destination:
        services:
          name: default-nginx-ingress-controller
          namespace: nginx-ingress
```

This particular policy is tailored to fail (no ingress allowed as you've might see). And I'm trying to open my application using the Ingress.

I see logs in journalctl

```
Mar 27 22:54:35 HOSTNAME kernel: calico-packet: IN=cali2946daffa48 OUT=cali4b2091ec068 MAC=ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:a6:8e:ee:53:38:b7:08:00 SRC=10.254.157.25 DST=10.254.157.20 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=10079 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35236 DPT=80 WINDOW=32640 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Mar 27 22:54:52 HOSTNAME kernel: calico-packet: IN=cali2946daffa48 OUT=cali4b2091ec068 MAC=ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:a6:8e:ee:53:38:b7:08:00 SRC=10.254.157.25 DST=10.254.157.20 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=10080 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35236 DPT=80 WINDOW=32640 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

And I can packets are dropped by the iptables due to policy mismatch counter is increasing

```
iptables-save -c | grep DROP
...
[76:4560] -A cali-tw-cali4b2091ec068 -m comment --comment "cali:dmC976zbMPTWTc-S" -m comment --comment "Drop if no policies passed packet" -m mark --mark 0x0/0x20000 -j DROP
...
```

My main goal here is to somehow identify the traffic that is being dropped by the "Drop if no policies passed packet" rule. Maybe there is something I'm missing in the journalctl calico-packet section that I cannot see, I don't know.

Could anyone point me to some identifier that explicitly denotes that the packets logged in journalctl were dropped?

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.